# Plotting a CDF graph in Mathematica yields wrong & strange result

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to visualize a random variable:

```
d[t_] := ProbabilityDistribution[If[x < t, t, t + 1], {x, 0, 1}]
```

When I plot the PDF, it looks fine

```
Plot[PDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

When I plot the CDF (the integral of the PDF from 0 to X), it doesn't look correct:

```
Plot[CDF[d[0.5], x ], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

If I do the same steps but using regular function definitions, everything looks fine.

```
reg[ t_, x_] := Piecewise[ {{t, x < t} , {t + 1, x >= t}}]
Integrate[ reg[t, x], {x, 0, y}, Assumptions -> { y  \[Element] Reals, 0 <=  y <=  1, 0 < t < 1}]
intg[y_, t_] := Piecewise[ {{t y, t - y >= 0}, {-t + y + t y, t - y < 0}}]
Plot[intg[x, 0.5], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Typing "CDF[d[0.5], 0.95]" yields the correct result (0.925), so it's the Plot[] that is acting weird.

Here are the pictures for illustration purposes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMWSR.jpg

Comment: If you use any symbol other than `x` in `Plot[CDF[d[0.5], x ], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]`, it works fine.  I assume that `x` "lingers" from use in the definition of `d[t_]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does seem to be a weird interaction between the CDF and the plotting. Consider:

```
d[t_] := ProbabilityDistribution[If[x < t, t, t + 1], {x, 0, 1}]; 
p[x_] = CDF[d[0.5], x];
{Plot[p[x], {x, 0, 1}], Plot[CDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}]}
```

[image]

The first makes sense while the second one doesn't.

Update: Jim Baldwin in the comments made the key observation that the problem lies with the variable `x`. Indeed, using any other letter in such as `Plot[CDF[d[0.5], z], {z, 0, 1}]` gives the correct result. Presumably this is due to a scoping issue where the `x` in the definition of `d` is interfering with the `x` in the CDF function.

As for the question of `Evaluate`, consider the various possibilities:

```
d[t_] := ProbabilityDistribution[If[x < t, t, t + 1], {x, 0, 1}];
p[x_] = CDF[d[0.5], x];
{Plot[p[x], {x, 0, 1}] // RepeatedTiming, 
 Plot[CDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}] // RepeatedTiming, 
 Plot[CDF[d[0.5], z], {z, 0, 1}] // RepeatedTiming, 
 Plot[Evaluate@CDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}] // RepeatedTiming}
```

[image]

By adding the Evaluate, the CDF call is only done once (like a Set rather than SetDelayed), and the scoping problem is also addressed.

Comment: The problem with the second one is the use of `x`.  If you use a symbol other than `x`, then it works as expected:  `Plot[CDF[d[0.5], z], {z, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: While true, this still doesn't explain why Evaluate makes it so much faster. Any ideas? Also,why PDF call is not affected by this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can even do this

```
d[t_] := ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{t, x < t}, {t + 1, x > t}}], {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate@CDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Not only it is correctly rendered, it is much faster

```
Plot[CDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.31844 *)

Plot[Evaluate@CDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.0408219 *)
```

Since `d` is defined with `SetDelayed`, we need to evaluate CDF? 
So, if we define `d` with simple `Set`, the `Plot` still takes longer to render, but at least it works without `Evaluate`:

```
d[t_] = ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{{t, x < t}, {t + 1, x > t}}], {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[CDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 1.22373 *)
```

Not sure I know why the `Evaluate` version is so much faster.

Comment: How does "Evaluate@" work? How does it differ from default behavior?

Comment: It evaluates previously held expression, but I am not sure I understand why it affects the Plot timing so much

Comment: By using Evaluate, you are forcing the evaluation of your distribution function that is defined with a delayed set.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for a delayed set here. This works fine:

```
d[t_] = ProbabilityDistribution[If[x < t, t, t + 1], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> ProbabilityDistribution[ If[\[FormalX] < t, t, t + 1], {\[FormalX], 0, 1}]

note the change to a FormalX..

```
Plot[CDF[d[0.5], x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Pre-evaluating `CDF` makes it considerably faster though.
Note now you will have a problem if you happen to use a FormalX as the plot variable.